# jQuery: Animate using CSS3 instead of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, animation, css

I'm converting a jQuery-based web application for use on iPad and need to make use of the hardware-accelerated performance of CSS3 animations. I'm already using fadeIn, fadeOut and some positioning animation so ideally I'd like a plugin which overrides these functions to make use of CSS3 without me having to change the core functionality.

I've searched around but can't find anyone that has tackled this problem, so I'm considering writing a plugin myself, but I wanted to make sure someone else hadn't already done it.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about checking out http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/

Comment: That looks like what I need! It behaves very strangely on mobile Safari, but I will see if I can contribute some improvements to the project.